# How can I get built-in metrics and add a custom metrics in Spring Boot Kafka Streams?

Tags: spring-boot, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams, metrics

I have a problem to add a custom metrics in Kafka Streams.

I made a Kafka Streams application with Spring Boot like this. [(Kafka Streams with Spring boot. Baeldung)](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-kafka-streams)
and deployed several of this app on k8s.

I want to know about avg number of processd message per second of each app instance. and it exists in Kafka Streams built-in thread metrics(process-rate). [(ref. Kafka Streams Metrics)](https://docs.confluent.io/platform/current/streams/monitoring.html#thread-metrics)

But, that metric use thread-id at tag key and so each app instance has different metric tag key.

**I'd like to use that metric value as the same tag key in each app instance.**

So, I came up with a solution. It's about using that built-in metric value to add a new custom metric.

But, **There's no specific information about how I get built-in metric values in source code and add a custom metric..**

In [ref](https://docs.confluent.io/platform/current/streams/monitoring.html#adding-your-own-metrics), there's a way to add a custom metrics but no specific information about how can I apply in source code.

Is there a way to solve this problem? Or is there any other way?

Comment: I assume you're asking about Spring Actuator metrics rather than JMX? Otherwise, you need to use something like Prometheus to consolidate metrics from all instances, where you can filter by thread/client id

Comment: Hmm.... That could be a way.
But I want a way that not using spring actuator or Prometheus.
In short, I wonder if there's a way to make a custom metric with custom tag key using built-in metrics and register it as mBean(Managed Bean).

Comment: I don't think it's possible to modify existing or internally registered metric names

Comment: You could, however, try to lookup any existing Metric Registry via Actuator, then loop over existing names, then define new ones based on those. Spring Boot uses Actuator and Micrometer, by default, so I'm not sure why you're looking for other options

Comment: I think I found a way . Kafka streams's thread metric tag key is made of "client-id + -StreamThread- + threadIdx".
In general in Kafka Streams, kafka client-id is made of application-id + unique value for each instance.
So, In Configuration, I set client-id to application-id. after that each app has the same tag key!! what I want..
Because there is a custom metric monitoring tool in use, I wanted a way that add a new custom metric. not using other options.
Thank you for comment, and I learned a lot from your comment. 

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Feel free to answer your own question below with code that works for you